# Will "left join table on ident_key = null" help query speed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

There are three tables, two upstream `table A and B`, and one downsteam `table C`. Records in `table A and B` are processed and merged into `table C`.

```
Table A ( id_a identity not null, prop, val )
Table B ( id_b identity not null, prop, val )
Table C ( id_c, 
    original_id [id_a or id_c],
    prop, processed_val, 
    source_table [ 'A' or 'B' ] )
NOTE: id_a and id_b has different format they never collide.
```

I need to correct some applicaton behaviour without accessing to the app code. so I am trying to attach a trigger on `table C` and manipulate the `process_val` depending on the original data.

I could do

```
UPDATE C 
SET processed_value = NEW_FUNCTION( coalesce(A.val,B.val) )
FROM inserted
LEFT JOIN A ON ( C.orginal_id = A.id )
LEFT JOIN B ON ( C.orginal_id = B.id )
```

But I think this will have to go through two table index before return the resut. I don't want to use dynamic query, I want to keep it simple as a sql procedure.

I wonder if sth like below will help prevent the redunant lookup, since these keys should not be `NULL`, will a `NULL` value stop the lookup ?

```
UPDATE C 
SET processed_value = NEW_FUNCTION( coalesce(A.val,B.val) )
FROM inserted
LEFT JOIN A ON ( A.id = case when source_table='A' then C.orginal_id else NULL end )
LEFT JOIN B ON ( B.id = case when source_table='B' then C.orginal_id else NULL end )
```

Or is there any other way in MSSQL to switch source table dynamically (without dynamic query)?

Comment: You should always check actual execution plans and statistics to compare relative performance. I bet the version with `CASE` could be even slower.

Comment: yeah, I should not alter the key, corrected. how about now ?

Comment: mssql is so demanding on setups, I don't have extra tools for query plan viewing... i dont have sql management studio either... so i guess i'd better just ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `JOIN` between `C` and `inserted`.  I would expect the logic to look more like this:

```
UPDATE C 
    SET processed_value = NEW_FUNCTION(coalesce(A.val, B.val))
    FROM inserted i JOIN
         C
         ON i.id_c = C.id_C LEFT JOIN
         A
         ON A.id = i.original_id AND i.source_table = 'A' LEFT JOIN
         B
         ON B.id = C.orginal_id AND i.source_table = 'B';
```

Comment: I guess, i was very confused. the a,b,c stuff is only an attempt to simplify the question, poorly done indeed. now I feel so weird, why would I want to nullify the condition. I must have been brain dead. Thanks. But for this specific question I am still curious, will a null be looked up in a `not null ` column like normal value? or just immediately return no match?

Comment: @Ben . . . I don't know.  I wouldn't be surprised if it were still be looked up, because looking up a value in an index is pretty fast.  A `NULL` check would be an improvement, but a slight improvement.